# No sound in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I've been working with the VSE for a while and everything was fine. But all of the sudden, when I play the preview the sound doesn't play. I think I must've disabled it somewhere, but I can't manage to find the place. It doesn't matter if I start a new project, sound doesn't play so I think it must be some kind of configuration. Does anyone know what could have happened? (Computer's sound is working fine)

EDIT:
I have found [this](https://developer.blender.org/T33840) thread. I'm running Blender on Debian 7.0 unstable, and maybe an update has messed my setup. Thing is that any other app works fine, music player, vlc, games, the only one that does not work is Blender, but as the link suggests it could be a setup problem not having to do with Blender. I'll do my homework and come back if I can manage to find a solution to post it here.

Comment: Can you post your .blend. I would say screen shots but I don't think that would be enough.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to upload a blend file, I can only see an icon to upload pictures. Anyway, I don't think it will be of any use, since starting a new project will give the same results, I can insert a new audio strip but when I hit play no sound is played. I can upload screenshots of user preferences if it can help just tell me if you want a specific configuration page or all of them.

Comment: What happens if you pick a different sound backend in *User preferences > System > Sound*?

Comment: I have tried both options SDL and OpenAL but with no use.

Comment: @YoMismo Upload it to dropbox, then link to it.

Comment: Ok, here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bDga1QTmVaOS1wbmx6cWM4RlE/edit?usp=sharing and two links to the first video/audio https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bDga1QTmVabkdvSERyM2M5c2s/edit?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bDga1QTmVaTTUyN1JydFJHZzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried the file you uploaded. the audio plays fine on my computer with Blender 2.71. Can you see the waveform if you enable 'Draw Waveform' for the track?

Comment: Yes, I can see it, but no audio is played. Check the edit I'm doing in the question, I found this might be a setup problem. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted the original sound of the video, and then added a sound strip. Blender did not play the sound. I saved the file, and restarted Blender. It played the sound! No settings change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the problem and the solution.

As the link I posted in the edited question suggested, the problem was some twisted setup, the last update should have messed something.

What I have done has been.

1. First I moved my `$HOME/.pulse to $HOME/.pulse_old` to start with a new setup.
2. I launched pavucontrol
3. Switched to setup tab.
4. Select my sound output device.

BINGO!!! now Blender VSE plays sounds again.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

EDIT:

This finally turned out not to be a Blender problem (eventhough I am not that sure, since it was the only program failing). Nevertheless, I am posting the solution since someone might benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a couple possibilities:

- Your audio track is muted in the VSE

  Select the track

  hit <kbd>n</kbd>

  deselect the 'eye' button

  [image: VSE track settings]
- Your sequence is no longer pointing to the audio file because you've moved it or the blend

  repath the file using the 'file location' tool button shown in the above image
- Your scene volume is set to 0

  goto the *Scene*  tab in the *Properties* frame

  expand the *Audio* panel

  adjust the volume or other settings

  [image]

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to answer. Audio is not muted, at least not with the eye icon, I have tried to set/remove a couple of times with no use. File path is ok, since audio playback fails even with a new project and opening a new audio file, so that shouldn't be the case. Volume doesn't seem to be the problem either, since I have tried raising it to the top and no sound is played either (The sound file plays correctly from outside Blender so audio source file is OK).

Comment: One thing I have to check as soon as I get home is the last image, I didn't know there was a volume in the scene section, I have raised the volume in the VSE strips, but I didn't know about the one in this section. As soon as I test this I'll post the result. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: No luck. I've checked the volume in the scene section and it was already at 1 which is the highest value, but no sound is playing :-(

Comment: I'm unable to post an answer, so I'll just suggest that this answer be updated to mention a solution that worked for me: restarting Blender.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this by:

1. Select *Render Properties*
2. Go Down Expand *Enconding*
3. On *Audio Codec:*
4. Choose dropdown from *None* to *MP3*

[image: a busy cat]

Now you can hear the sound, cheers!

Comment: Wrong advice? How do you know it was wrong advice? The problem appeared and was solved without modifying a bit of the .blend file. The problem was solved (read the above answer marked as solved) just reconstructing pulse audio's configuration directory...

Comment: well i'm using pavucontrol but there's no setup tab , only configuration tab, and there's no option "Select my sound output device.". I'm Using Xubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then I realized I had moved the original audio files somewhere else. This is a common problem with Blender so you must always make sure to keep your files in a project-related folder