# Renders with video editing has no sound

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, video, audio

Whenever I try and render a video in blender (to be specific, I am using the 5th option that blender supplies me with, video editing), it comes out without sound. When I watch the project in the editor, it has sound. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the rendering. I'm rendering it as an FFmpeg video. Please, it's for a school project. Can someone tell me why, and how to fix it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24357/vse-how-to-render-a-video-with-audio https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14509/no-sound-in-vse https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/adding-sound-in-blender